# url_for() does not render files in sub directories

Tags: html

In my .html file, I have used:

`<img href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/images/logo.png') }}" alt="highbrow">`

This is not rendering the image.
My file structure looks like this:

```
/projects
    /highbrow
        app.py
        /highbrow
            __init__.py
            main.py
            /templates
            /static
                (bunch of .css files)
                /js
                    (bunch of .js files)
                /images
                    (bunch of images)
```

The **init**.py is like:

```
create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    return app
```

The route function with the problem is like:

```
@route("/post/<string:post_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def post(post_id):
    post = fetch_post(post_id) # fetches the post from database
    comment_form = PostForm()
    if comment_form.validate_on_submit() and request.method == "POST":
        comment_entry = {
            "username": "foobar",
            "user_profile_link": "/foobar",
            "time": 0,
            "comment": comment_form.comment.data
        }
        comments.append(comment_entry)
    return render_template("post.html", comment_form=comment_form, comments=comments,
                           number_of_comments=post["comments"], post_details=post, notifications=notifications)
```

In my html file, it is like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Highbrow</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<link rel=icon type="image/x-icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/logo.png') }}">
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='line-awesome.css') }}">
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='line-awesome-font-awesome.min.css') }}">
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='font-awesome.min.css') }}">
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

</head>


<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header-data">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="/" title=""><img href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/images/logo.png') }}" alt="highbrow"></a>
                    </div><!--logo end-->
...
...
```

The **.css** files render just fine, but the **img** does not render. it only shows the alt text. Just like this:

[image: proof of picture not being rendered]

There should be the logo.png here.

The console says:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2021 00:16:35] "GET /post/0562262d-85f3-45d1-bf64-f2f539653468 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2021 00:16:35] "GET /static/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2021 00:16:35] "GET /static/line-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2021 00:16:35] "GET /static/line-awesome-font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2021 00:16:35] "GET /static/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2021 00:16:35] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2021 00:16:35] "GET /static/fonts/line-awesome.woff2?v=1.1. HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2021 00:16:36] "GET /static/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It just stops here even though there are more images and .js files to render. Notice the last *GET* it show status 200 but still doesn't load the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to add an extra leading slash. You have to use `src` attribute in place of `href`

the code should be :

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/logo.png') }}" alt="highbrow">
```

Comment: Right.  To be specific, it is that LEADING slash that causes a problem.  That makes it look for `/image`, not `/static/image`, which is what the OP needs.

Comment: No that make it look for `/static//image/logo.png`

Comment: It does not change anything. It is still the same result. Edit: even the console logs are the same.

Comment: are you sure that there is logo.png in your static folder. go on inspect tab and check what is the url of the image. try right clicking on the url and visit it on another page. Is the url found?

Comment: Ok I just inspected it, the url being shown is `/static/images/logo.png` but it should be `static/images/logo.png`. I don't know where the leading / comes from. I removed it from my code.

Comment: I understood the problem is that you are using href attribute but it should be src attribute in img tag. I have edited my answer. you can check

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I changed it all to `src` and now it is working.